# Is it possible to only pick part of a UDP packet to receive?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, sensors, multicast

I am trying to receive a multicast UDP packet. The packet has a timestamp and some other useless data as well as sensor readings. Is there a way to only receive the last part of the packet, which would be the last 16 bytes out of the total 110 byte message? This would effectively take only the sensor readings and ignore the rest of the UDP package.

Comment: Nope.  Read the whole thing, and pull out what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The packet also sends out hex values for the sensor readings that are supposed to be converted to decimal form. But the rest of the packet needs to be converted to strings, is there a way I could do this?

Comment: Of course.  But *how* you'd do that is a whole other question.  It depends on what exactly your data looks like

Comment: I appreciate your help. If you have time to look, the data comes like this, [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/rn-wiflycr-ug-v1.2r.pdf) on page 73.

Comment: The docs are a bit vague on what exactly should be in those bytes.  But it's probably a set of eight 16-bit integers.  Little-endian or big, i couldn't tell ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you want is at the beginning of the packet, yes, by providing a buffer only large enough to hold the data you want. Otherwise no.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the data I want is at the end of the packet.